# What does "ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4048)" mean using the Python ssl library?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, fastapi

I am trying to connect my python service to postgres using ssl connection and "verify-ca".
Here's the code

```
import os
import ssl

DATABASE_URL = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]

# using ssl connection for connecting to DB
sslctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile='/etc/config/root.pem')
sslctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
sslctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='/etc/config/server.pem', keyfile='/etc/config/pkey.key')

# databases query builder
database = Database(DATABASE_URL, ssl = sslctx)
```

It shows the error like this

```
 File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 362, in main
    run(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 386, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 48, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 55, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 308, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.db.db import database
  File "./app/db/db.py", line 11, in <module>
    sslctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='/etc/config/server.pem', keyfile='/etc/config/pkey.key')
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4048)
```

The certs are flowing in the container, that is for sure. I am confused why is it not able to read the certs?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a location in the source code. First lookup the version of the Python library, then the version of the SSL library that it depends on, and finally lookup the source code to find the issue. Unfortunately with this library you'll need to jump to these *version specific* hoops. It doesn't make too much sense for us to do this for you as any change in the source code will produce a different error (and yes, that's not very user friendly, sorry).